# Restricting user from entering specific character in dynamically generated textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to prevent user from entering two specific characters in any of the textboxes on the page. The code I am using does not work with dynamically appended textboxes.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a4NSm/12/)

```
  window.onload = function () {
            $("input").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which === 44 || e.which === 124) {//preventing , and |
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
}
```

And since I am not using server controls I can not use ajax filter etc. I would like to have a simple solution to this. Without causing any conflicts in the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`event-delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in this context, since you need to bind events for the elements which are being appended at the run time.

```
 $(document).on('keypress',"input",function (e) {
       if (e.which === 44 || e.which === 124) {
            e.preventDefault();
       }
 });
```

**Side Note:** I just use `document` for delegating the event, but you should probably use any closest static parent to the input element, in order to attain a performance boos up.

Comment: Thank you bro. It works. I do not however know why your code works and mine doesnt. I guess I need to read about event-delegation.

Comment: @Arbaaz Glad to help..! Just read the article which was given by me. you will come to know about event-delegation.. :)

Answer (score 1):

use event delegation for dynamically created dom

```
$(document).on("keypress","input",function (e) {
                if (e.which === 44 || e.which === 124) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
```

`document` use immediate parent selector which is static in html

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4v78q/

http://jsfiddle.net/4v78q/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").each(function(){
        $(this).keypress(function(e){
            var keycode = e.which || e.keyCode; 
             if (keycode === 44 || keycode === 124) {
                 e.preventDefault();
             }
        });
    });
});
```